# 404 component not found when trying to use custom component in Joomla

Tags: xml, joomla, components, content-management-system

I am trying to create a custom component in my Joomla backend, so I created this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="3.8.1" method="upgrade">
<name>administratie</name>
<creationDate>2019-04-09</creationDate>
<author>Twan</author>
<authorEmail>you@example.com</authorEmail>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<description>Administratie dashboard</description>
<administration>
<menu>administratie</menu>

<files folder="components/com_administratie/admin">
<file>administratie.php</file>
</files>
</administration>
</extension>
```

And installed it, which worked, the `administratie` link is added in my components drop down, except when I click on it, the page shows a `404 component not found` error.

Maybe I wrote something wrong in my xml file? I can't find what it is. This is my folder structure:

```
administrator
-components
--com_administratie
---admin
---administratie.xml
----administratie.php (this file has a simple echo in it)
```

I already tried refreshing the cache but I keep getting the same error.

I am on Joomla version: `Joomla! 3.8.1 Stable`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<files folder="components/com_administratie/admin">
```

to

```
<files folder="admin">
```

and reinstall the component!

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Comment: If you have Joomla knowledge to share, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.